# How to consume endpoint multipe times depending on result

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

Trying to consume endpoint which returns `{"next": boolean, "result": [some data]}` where "next" is indicator that there is more data/pages.
We use vert.x's web client and rxjava api, and so far succeeded with following code:

```
public Single<JsonArray> getData() {
    return Observable
            .range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .flatMapSingle(page -> Single.just(webClient.getAbs(API_URL + "?page=" + page)
                        .rxSend()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .blockingGet()))
            .takeUntil(response -> response.bodyAsJsonObject().getBoolean("next") == false)
            .map(response -> {
                if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                    return response.bodyAsJsonObject().getJsonArray("results");
                }

            })
            .collect(JsonArray::new, JsonArray::addAll);
}
```

We are also sure that this is not good approach... creating a new thread and then block it. Could anyone suggest the right approach, thanks.

UPDATE: Non blocking solution with BehaviorSubject:

```
public Single<JsonArray> getData(Instant start, Instant end, Integer departmentId, Integer duration) {
        BehaviorSubject<Integer> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(1);

        return pageControl
                .concatMapSingle(page -> webClient.getAbs(API_URL + "?page=" + page)
                        .rxSend()
                        .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                            if (response.bodyAsJsonObject().getBoolean("next")) {
                                pageControl.onNext(pageControl.getValue() + 1);
                            } else {
                                pageControl.onComplete();
                            }
                        })
                        .doOnError(pageControl::onError))
                .map(response -> {
                    if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
            return response.bodyAsJsonObject().getJsonArray("results");
                    }
                })
                .collect(JsonArray::new, JsonArray::addAll);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `blockingGet`. Instead, invoke `webClient.rxGetAbs`

Comment: There is no such method, rxSend() is used (returns Single<HttpResponse<T>>) .

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, `blockingGet` will block the event loop, and that's breaking the [Vert.x golden rule](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule).

An async recursive function will help here:

```
public Single<JsonArray> getData() {
  return loadPage(0).collect(JsonArray::new, JsonArray::addAll);
}

public Observable<JsonArray> loadPage(int page) {
  return webClient.getAbs(API_URL + "?page=" + page)
    .expect(ResponsePredicate.SC_OK)
    .expect(ResponsePredicate.JSON)
    .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
    .rxSend()
    .flatMapObservable(response -> {
      JsonObject body = response.body();
      Observable<JsonArray> results = Observable.just(body.getJsonArray("results"));
      return !body.getBoolean("next") ? results : results.concatWith(loadPage(page + 1));
    });
}
```

With such a function, the pages will always be loaded one after the other, and no extra request will be made.

Note that to simplify status, content type, and body handling, the snippet above makes use of response *predicates* and *body codec*.

Comment: Thanks @tsegismont, it works... I updated question with my solution also.